# Solving Recurrence relation $a_n = 3a_{n-1} + 5 \cdot 3^n$ for $n\geq 1, a_0=2$?

Tags: recurrence-relations

How can I solve recurrence relation $a_n = 3a_{n-1} + 5 \cdot 3^n$ for $n \geq1 $ and $a_0 = 2$?

Comment: have you tried doing some values and finding a guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$a_{n+1} - 3a_n = 5 \cdot 3^{n+1} = 3 (a_n-3a_{n-1})$$

Can you start from here?

> $$a_{n+1} - 6a_n + 9a_{n-1} = 0 \implies \frac{a_{n+1}}{3^{n+1}} - 2\frac{a_n}{3^n} + \frac{a_{n-1}}{3^{n-1}}=0$$ Let $a_n = 3^n b_n$ then $$b_{n+1} - 2b_n  + b_{n-1} = 0 \implies b_{n+1} - b_{n} = b_n-b_{n-1} = \cdots = b_1 - b_0 = 7 - 2 =5$$ Therefore $b_n=b_0+5n=5n+2, a_n = 3^n (5n+2). \blacksquare$

Comment: In this particular problem we can start with $a_n = 3^n b_n$ in the very beginning and derive $b_n$ as an arithmetic sequence. But if the coefficient is something else (e.g., $a_n=2a_{n-1}+5\cdot 3^n$) then it's better to make it homogeneous first.

Answer (score 1):

Put
$$a_n=5.3^n.b_n$$

then

$$5.3^n.b_n=3.5.3^{n-1}.b_{n-1}+5.3^n$$

thus

$$b_n=b_{n-1}+1$$

So,
$$b_n=n+2,\; \; and \; \; a_n=5.3^n(n+2)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $ n\in\mathbb{N} $, we have for any $ k\leq n-1 $ the following : $$ a_{n-k}=3a_{n-k-1}+5\times 3^{n-k} $$

Thus : \begin{aligned}3^{k}a_{n-k}&=3^{k+1}a_{n-k-1}+5\times 3^{n}\\ \Longrightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(3^{k}a_{n-k}-3^{k+1}a_{n-k-1}\right)}&=5n\times 3^{n}\\ \iff \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ a_{n}-3^{n}a_{0}&=5n\times 3^{n}\\ \iff \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ a_{n}&=3^{n}\left(5n+2\right)\end{aligned}

Since $ n $ is arbitrary, the result stands for all $ n\in\mathbb{N} $.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a first-order recurrence like this, you can often simply ‘unwind’ it:

$$\begin{align*}
a_n&=3a_{n-1}+5\cdot3^n\\
&=3(3a_{n-2}+5\cdot3^{n-1})+5\cdot3^n\\
&=3^2a_{n-2}+2\cdot5\cdot3^n)\\
&=3^2(3a_{n-3}+5\cdot3^{n-2})+2\cdot5\cdot3^n\\
&=\color{red}{3^3a_{n-3}+3\cdot5\cdot3^n}\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
&=\color{blue}{3^ka_{n-k}+k\cdot5\cdot3^n}\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
&=3^na_0+n\cdot5\cdot3^n\\
&=3^n(2+5n)
\end{align*}$$

By the time you get to the red line, the pattern should be pretty clear; I’ve expressed it in general terms in the blue line. Then you can jump to the end and simplify to get a closed form for $a_n$. The step from the red to the blue line isn’t rigorous, so properly speaking you should prove by induction on $n$ that the formula $a_n=3^n(5n+2)$ really does satisfy the recurrence with the right initial condition, though in many cases, like this one, the pattern really is very clear.

Answer (score -2):

general sequence is $a_n= (3^n)a_0 +n \times 5\times 3^n$
substitute $a(n-1)$ for $a(n-2)$ and check the pattern you can easily figure it out.